# Do all Dr Seuss stories share the same Fantasy world?

Tags: dr-seuss

I know that Whos are featured in multiple stories (the Grinch and Horton hears a Who for example), but I am no expert in his other works.

I'm not looking for a listing of his stories,  but I'd like to know if they all share a common 'fantasy world'.

Comment: THEY'RE NOT TRUE???????????!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: I don't think Dr. Suess stories fit the definition of fantasy.  http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/683/are-childrens-literature-and-cartoons-for-children-on-topic

Comment: Hmm, tiny fluffy creatures exist in plants and can communicate to an elephant (due to its large ears), via a spout. sounds pretty fantastical to me.

Comment: I've seen Dr Suess questions here. I've seen them there. I've seen them everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

### No, they almost certainly do not.

The 500 hundred hats of Bartholomew Cubbins clearly states that it took place in the Kingdom of Didd:

> IN THE beginning, Bartholomew Cubbins didn’t have five hundred hats.
> He had only one hat. It was an old one that had belonged to his father and
> his father’s father before him. It was probably the oldest and the plainest hat
> in the whole Kingdom of Didd, where Bartholomew Cubbins lived.

Yet the Grinch Stole Christmas takes place in Whoville:

> Every Who Down in Whoville Liked Christmas a lot...
> But the Grinch,Who lived just north of Whoville, Did NOT!

And its highly unlikely Whoville is located in the Kingdom of Didd as a perusal of the pictures show two extremely distinct places:

Kingdom of Didd (highly classsical buildings, very unimaginary)
[image: Kingdom of Didd]

Whoville, very imaginary:

[image: Whoville]

Also, Hunches in Bunches mentions real-world Boise, Idaho as an alternative location for the Narrator to visit, but that could just be an out-of-universe alternative and may not show where the books take place.

Comment: Worlds are pretty big places...there's no reason to assume that Didd & Whoville exist in different worlds any more than there's reason to assume they exist in the same world.